# How is Twitter's rate limit counted in the context of bookmarklets? 

Tags: twitter, bookmarklet

So, I'm using Twitter's [user timeline method](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) in a bookmarklet. As you may know, the user timeline method is rate limited; you can only call it 150 times in an hour. My question is, how would it count against my limit when the call happens within the bookmarklet?

The corny mess is here:

[We Still At War?](http://jkdjkdjkd.zxq.net/war/war.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are embedding your credentials in the bookmarklet, then everyone will be contributing to the rate limiting, because I believe it is by token per application. But that would be silly.

Unauthenticated timeline REST requests count against the IP they are called from. So these would count against the person browsing, not you. This is the same as how people view twitter.com when they aren't logged in.

Comment: Well that's awesome. Thanks, I thought this would never get answered :)

Comment: glad to help, remember, when you see "requires auth: supported" rather than "requires auth: yes" on the twitter docs it means it's allowed, but not required.